# Assign SSIS 2012 "isserverexec" process to single CPU core using Start Affinity

Tags: ssis

In SSIS 2008 we used to run the packages in parallel by assigning "DtExec" Process using Start Affinity method.

But in SSIS 2012 the packages are executed by External process "ISserverexec". 
So the Question is, Is there any option for assigning each package process "ISserverexec" to specific CPU in multicore processors machine

Thanks

Comment: Having never done this, could you help me understand why starting the steps you used for dtexec process don't apply to isserverexec?

Comment: Sure, In SSIS 2008 DtExec is a command line utility and by using this we can call/Execute the packages, But SSIS 2012 comes with New SSIS Catalog and the SSIS packages are launched by DtExec but executed by CLR Procedure and this CLR proc Invokes "ISserverexec" which cannot be used as command line i believe . for your reference this Exe located at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\ISServerExec.exe".
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a sample for setting a affinity 
"Start /Affinity 1 /Min DTEXEC /F Master.DtsX"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISServerExec is started with catalog.start_execution in SSISDB, which invokes an internal SQLCLR stored procedure that creates the ISServerExec.exe process. Executing it with dtexec.exe /ISSERVER even executes the package with ISServerExec.exe

AFAIK, there is no way to limit the resources to the SSIS package in 2012/2014, such as CPU cores. Like e.g. resource governor in SQL Server.

There are a couple of workarounds.

1. If you are using Windows Server 2008R2 or before (which you probably aren't, if running SQL Server 2012), you could use Windows System Resource Manager. Note that it is deprecated in Windows Server 2012 and above.
2. Or you could play around with the MaxConcurrentExecutables property on the control flow or EngineThreads in the data flow. This is what I usual do, and found works the best. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141031.aspx